# Difference between equilibrium points and critical points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out a qualitative difference between a critical point and an equilibrium point in the context of autonomous ODE

Let us consider the following Cauchy problem:

$ y'(t) = f(y(t))$, with $y(0)=y_0$.

Formally, I know the difference between the two.
However in the above context we have:

$y_1\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a critical point $ \Leftrightarrow y_1'(t) = 0  \Leftrightarrow  f(y_1(t)) = 0  \Leftrightarrow y_1$ is an equilibrium point.

Is there an error in this reasonning?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are critical points where it isn't that the derivative is zero, but that it doesn't exist. So your very first "iff" doesn't quite work there.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. could you please elaborate?

Comment: I understand your point now. However,  I think the first iff is valid because every solution of the EDO, where $f$ is continuous regarding $t $ and $y$ is of class $C^1$. So $y'(t)$ exists.